# uploadify upload not starting when being called from inside a function

Tags: ajax, jquery-plugins, jquery, uploadify

Everything is working correctly but the uploadifyUpload() function doesn't appear to be triggering. It is not accessing the add_list.php script whatsoever.

Here is my code from my header..

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#sampleFile').uploadify({
        'uploader': 'include/uploadify/uploadify.swf',
        'script': 'add_list.php',
        'scriptData': {'mode': 'upload', 'page_title': '', 'list_title': '', 'list_columns': '', 'list_records': '', 'list_price': '', 'payment_url': '', 'list_desc': ''},
        'fileDataName': 'sampleFile',
        'folder': '/work/avais/lists',
        'cancelImg': 'include/uploadify/cancel.png',
        'queueID': 'sampleQueue'
    });

    $("#add_list").submit(function(){

        var $upload = $("#sampleFile");

        $upload.uploadifySettings('scriptData', { 'page_title': $('#page_title').val() });
        $upload.uploadifySettings('scriptData', { 'list_title': $('#list_title').val() });
        $upload.uploadifySettings('scriptData', { 'list_columns': $('#list_columns').val() });
        $upload.uploadifySettings('scriptData', { 'list_records': $('#list_records').val() });
        $upload.uploadifySettings('scriptData', { 'list_price': $('#list_price').val() });
        $upload.uploadifySettings('scriptData', { 'payment_url': $('#payment_url').val() });
        $upload.uploadifySettings('scriptData', { 'list_desc': $('#list_desc').val() });

        /***** Error Check *****/

        // Set params
        var params = "page_title=" + $('#page_title').val() + "&list_title=" + $('#list_title').val() + "&list_columns=" + $('#list_columns').val() + "&list_records=" + $('#list_records').val() + "&list_price=" + $('#list_price').val() + "&payment_url=" + $('#payment_url').val() + "&list_desc=" + $('#list_desc').val();

        // Send ajax request off
        errorCheck('error_check.php', params, (function(ajaxResponse) {

            if (ajaxResponse == 'false') {
                alert('Correct');
                $("#sampleFile").uploadifyUpload(); // Triggers the upload to start.
            } else {
                alert(ajaxResponse);
            }

        }));

    });

});
```

It correctly shows an alert box with "Correct" so I know it's getting in there to run it, but it just isn't running.

Here is the errorCheck() function if interested..

```
function errorCheck(url, params, callback) {

    // Create AJAX object    
    var myAJAX = createAJAXobject();

    // Retrieve data
    myAJAX.open("post",url,true);

    // Send the proper header information along with the request
    myAJAX.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    myAJAX.setRequestHeader("Content-length", params.length);
    myAJAX.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");    

    myAJAX.onreadystatechange = function() {

        // Was it a success?

        if (myAJAX.readyState < 4) {
            return false;
        }

        // Set results
        var res = myAJAX.responseText;

        /* Returns results */

        // Run the callback function

        try {
            callback(res);
        } catch (e) {
            return false;
        }

    }

    myAJAX.send(params);

}
```

Comment: Let's see that there "errorCheck" function.

Comment: Didn't think it would be needed since I was always getting a correct response returned from it, but alas I have just added it above :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok.... please disregard. I'm an idiot...... I didn't select a file to upload.. I was too busy filling in all the other fields & simply forgot to select a file LMAO